# Stop my NSURLSession if the response returns a status code other than 200? in SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch, nsurlsession

I'm trying to load an image using NSURLSession. 
How can I do to "stop" the NSURLSession if the response returns a status code other than 200? I would like to display a network issue pop up.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() 
   {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        loadData()
   }

    func loadData()
  {
          self.downloadFullImageFrom("https://www.google.fr/logos/doodles/2015/holidays-2015-day-3-6399865393250304-5649050225344512-ror.jpg") { image in

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) 
            {
                //DO SOMETHING WITH images IF DOWNLOAD IS OK
                //HOW CAN I KNOW IF dataTaskWithURL FAILED?
            }
        }
    }

    func downloadFullImageFrom(url:String, completion: ((image: UIImage?) -> Void)) {

        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(NSURL(string: url)!) {(data, response, error) in

            if let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse 
           {

                if httpResponse.statusCode == 200
                {
                    completion(image: UIImage(data: data!))
                } 
                else { return }
            }
        }
          task.resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use delegate-rendition if you want to immediately cancel the request as soon as you see a non-200 response header without continuing to receive the body of the request. But frankly there's little benefit in doing that, as the body associated with the non-200 response is generally extremely short and (generally a little HTML message explaining the error). Just receive the response as you have in your `dataTaskWithURL` and act accordingly there (e.g. dispatch the display of some message to the main queue and call your completion handler with `nil` for the image).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using guard to unwrap your optionals and add the where clause to control the expected results, in case of failure just return nil:

```
func loadData() {
   downloadFullImageFrom("https://www.google.fr/logos/doodles/2015/holidays-2015-day-3-6399865393250304-5649050225344512-ror.jpg") { image in
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            guard let image = image else {
                print("error loading image")
                return
            }
            //DO SOMETHING WITH images IF DOWNLOAD IS OK
            print(image.size)
        }
    }
}
func downloadFullImageFrom(link: String, completion: ((image: UIImage?) -> Void)) {
    guard let url = NSURL(string: link) else {
        completion(image: nil)
        return
    }
    NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url) {(data, response , error) in
        guard
            let httpURLResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse where httpURLResponse.statusCode == 200,
            let data = data, image = UIImage(data: data) where error == nil else {
                // display a network issue pop up
                print("======= statusCode =======")
                print((response as? NSHTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode)
                completion(image: nil)
                return
        }
        completion(image: image)
    }.resume()
}
```

**Xcode 8.3.1 • Swift 3.1**

```
func loadData() {
    downloadFullImageFrom(link: "https://www.google.fr/logos/doodles/2015/holidays-2015-day-3-6399865393250304-5649050225344512-ror.jpg") { image in
        DispatchQueue.main.async() {
            guard let image = image else {
                print("error loading image")
                return
            }
            //DO SOMETHING WITH images IF DOWNLOAD IS OK
            print(image.size)
        }
    }
}
func downloadFullImageFrom(link: String, completion: @escaping ((UIImage?) -> Void)) {
    guard let url = URL(string: link) else {
        completion(nil)
        return
    }
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
        guard
            let httpURLResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
            httpURLResponse.statusCode == 200,
            let data = data,
            let image = UIImage(data: data),
            error == nil
        else {
            // display a network issue pop up
            print("======= statusCode =======")
            print((response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode ?? "")
            completion(nil)
            return
        }
        completion(image)
    }.resume()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace return with

```
completion(image: nil)
```

in your method definition. And check if `image` is nil inside

```
dispatch_async
```